# Changing locale programmatically on DroidX(2.1 Update 1) does not work?

Tags: android, locale

I am trying to change the locale programmatically on Android. The code I have below works fine on the Incredible(2.2) and Droid(2.2). However, it doesn't on the DroidX(2.1 Update 1)

Anyone here have encountered similar problem ?? Any insight would be helpful.

```
public void overrideLocale(String languageToLoad) { 
    Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale; 

    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, null);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(languageToLoad);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = getBaseContext().getResources().getConfiguration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

Answer (score 0):

This just don't work for Droid-X, very sad - it doesn't allow to change locale from inside the application.